# Why swashbuckle example value does not work?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

Here I added XML doc parameter `example="this does not work"` for swashbuckle framework.

```
/// <summary>Gets a user by id.</summary>
/// <param name="id" example="this does not work">The id of user.</param>
/// <returns>got user.</returns>
[HttpGet("Get")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(UserDTO), 200)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(AppException), StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string id)
{
    return HandleResult(await _userServices.GetUserAsync(id));
}
```

But example value does not appear in Swagger UI.

[image]

Where I should look for the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found why it didn't worked. I changed in my project this setting: `app.UseSwagger(c => c.SerializeAsV2 = true)` to `app.UseSwagger()` and everything works now.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately out of the box Swashbuckle doesn't support the example tag/attribute. You need to write an operation filter and implement your own. Or you can use the `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters` nuget package.

You need to add the following code in your program.cs file.

```
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
    var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
    c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath, includeControllerXmlComments: true);
});
//For Example tag support
builder.Services.AddSwaggerExamplesFromAssemblies(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
```

And once you run the app you will be able to see examples like this in your swagger documentation.

[image: Swagger documentation with Example]

Comment: I added following code    `services.AddSwaggerExamplesFromAssemblies(typeof(UsersController).Assembly)` after `AddSwaggerGen`, but example values still doesn't generates for me.

Comment: Found why it didn't worked. I changed in my project `app.UseSwagger(c => c.SerializeAsV2 = true)` to  `app.UseSwagger()` and every thing works now. Thanks for solution!